# "HOWEVER, this browser is out of date"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, browsers, update

I keep getting the browser is out of date message even tho I click on the onion, download the latest Tor Bundle & install it.  Any suggestions?

I'm asking because I sometimes have an issue with the browser.  For ex. I am on citibank.com, walmart.com or homedepot.com, I can log in, then I click on an item & the page goes blank or I get a message that I don't have permission to access the site from this server.  When I try to log back in I'm blocked.  So... hoping it might have something to do with the browser & not because I'm using Tor.

Anyway, I shouldn't be getting that message after I've installed the lastest bundle.

Comment: I've had this similar issue for months. 1. So far, it is ONLY on Citi's site, and I get the same issue for all 5 browsers that I use (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera, and Internet Explorer 11).
2. The installed browser version doesn't matter. All my browsers are the latest public release available. I've even rolled back to older archived versions - same issue.
3. I ONLY get this issue when accessing Citi via a URL link in a Word document or an Excel cell. It does NOT occur in Outlook.
4. It doesn't matter which browser is default.
5. I can copy and paste the exact data from my Excel cell - direct

Answer (score 1):

click on [Help] and select [About], and see if you are actually running the latest version. it's possible you installed the newer version to a different directory, and your start menu link isn't pointing to it. in that case you need to find out where it did install the newest version, and edit your start menu to point to it. this works differently with different operating systems (and versions/distributions of operating systems). you can find the newer version by doing a search for firefox.exe (windows), firefox-bin (linux and mac), look at the details like the file dates, and determine where the newest one is.