# Why is TBB telling me "Your version of Firefox is out of date"?

Tags: firefox, update

In this last version of Tor Browser Bundle (TBB), I keep seeing this popup.  At first I thought I was out of date, so I checked.  This came after an auto update.  But I'm not out of date.

[image: Your version of Firefox is out of date]

You can see my versions here:
[image: TBB is up to date]

What is going on?  Is this an infection, a bug, or something in between?  Is this just an overlooked setting in this version of Firefox?

I found [this article](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/however-this-browser-is-out-of-date), but it's an old question, doesn't have any pictures, and doesn't have any kind of an answer to fix anything.

Answer (score 3):

THIS IS HIGHLY INFORMATIVE...

-From the [Tor Blog](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-603-released):

> "Update (August 11, 10:04 UTC): Starting from a couple of hours ago Tor
>   Browser users might see a notification box in their browser claiming
>   that Firefox is too old providing a button to get a newer one. This is
>   both due to a server-side code change on Mozilla's side and an
>   oversight by us during the ESR45 transition. Clicking on the "Get
>   Firefox" button is safe and leads the user to our Tor Browser download
>   page. Needless to say, this whole behavior is highly confusing and we
>   apologize for it. We are working on a fix as quickly as possible and
>   hope to get Mozilla to exempt Tor Browser users from this feature
>   while we are working on a new release. For technical details see our
>   bug tracker."